# Sort array of objects by field and then alphabetically

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
  [
      {name: 'George', favNum: '1'},
      {name: 'Susan', favNum: '2'},
      {name: 'Bob', favNum: '1'},
      {name: 'Anna', favNum: '2'}
  ]
```

I want to sort the array first by the `favNum` field and then alphabetically
within the resulting sort order. The end result would look like this:

```
  [
      {name: 'Bob', favNum: '1'},
      {name: 'George', favNum: '1'},
      {name: 'Anna', favNum: '2'},
      {name: 'Susan', favNum: '2'}
  ]
```

Is there a way to do with with Javascript? To give context, I've tried something like this after searching through other posts but am still having trouble getting the right sort order:

```
.sort((first, second) => {
      if (first.favNum === second.favNum) {
        return first.name > second.name ? 1 : -1
      }

      return first.favNum >= second.favNum
    })
```

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/9xbe2nsr/

Comment: Actually, if you want to sort by the favNum field first, and then alphabetically you will have to perform the operations in reverse order (ie: first, sort alphabetically and then by the favNum field).

Comment: Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/9xbe2nsr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first sort my `favNum` and then use `localeCompare` to sort by name.

```js
var data = [{name: 'George', favNum: '1'},{name: 'Susan', favNum: '2'},{name: 'Bob', favNum: '1'},{name: 'Anna', favNum: '2'}]
  
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.favNum - b.favNum || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
})

console.log(data)
```